# GitHub Copilot not working for Go but workin for JS in VSCode

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, github-copilot

I recently installed GitHub Copilot in VSCode and followed the instructions [here](https://docs.github.com/en/copilot/getting-started-with-github-copilot?tool=vscode). It is showing me suggestions for JS correctly as advertised there but when I try with Go, I am not getting any suggestions. Even a simple function like the one below does not offer a single one. How do I get it to show suggestions for Go as that is m primary coding language?

```
// add two numbers
func add(x, y int) int {}
```

This is the log for Copilot for the above code:

```
[INFO] [default] [2023-04-12T06:26:27.579Z] [fetchCompletions] engine https://copilot-proxy.githubusercontent.com/v1/engines/copilot-codex
[INFO] [default] [2023-04-12T06:26:27.808Z] request.response: [https://copilot-proxy.githubusercontent.com/v1/engines/copilot-codex/completions] took 229 ms
[INFO] [streamChoices] [2023-04-12T06:26:27.808Z] request done: headerRequestId: [] model deployment ID: []
```

Comment: @Jawla I actually started using Goland and found it much better than VS Code. And Copilot works there.